# i want only one country for one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want only one country for one row.

I joined two columns.

```
SELECT  
    brief_title AS Title,
    study_type  AS [Study Type],
    location_countries_country + location_facility_address_country AS Country,
FROM 
    [dbo].[ClinicalTrialStaging] 
WHERE
    study_type = 'all' 
    AND (location_countries_country LIKE '%United States%' OR 
         location_facility_address_country LIKE '%United States%')
```

I got this result :

```
Country
----------------------------
United States|United States|
United States|United States|
United States|United States|
```

I got two countries for the same row, but I want only one country for a particular row

Comment: Edit your post put the code on a snippet it's easier to read =/

Comment: Also, please elaborate the tables a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to

```
    GROUP BY country
```

Example:

```
    location_countries_country + location_facility_address_country AS Country 
    from customer         
    WHERE (location_countries_country like '%United States%' or 
    location_facility_address_country like '%United States%')
    GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: Actually in most SQL dialects, the `GROUP BY` must be **after** the `WHERE` clause ...

Comment: My bad, just forgot to change it to having

Comment: But `HAVING` should only be applied to **aggregated** columns - e.g. if you use `SUM` or `COUNT` - not for "normal" conditions such as a `LIKE`.....